# How can I change Tailwind Element's component parameters

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

I using Tailwind Element's sidebar component which appears and disappears when a button is clicked. The sidebar which appears has a fixed width of `240px` and I want change this width. I can't find where can I change it. The component has this structure

```html
<nav id="cart-nav" style="width: 240px; height: 100vh; position: fixed; transition: all 0.3s linear 0s; transform: translateX(0%);" class="fixed right-0 top-0 z-[1035] h-screen w-96 translate-x-full overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-[0_4px_12px_0_rgba(0,0,0,0.07),_0_2px_4px_rgba(0,0,0,0.05)] data-[te-sidenav-hidden='false']:-translate-x-0 sidenav-primary group/ps [overflow-anchor:none] [overflow-style:none] touch-none" data-te-sidenav-init="" data-te-sidenav-hidden="true" data-te-sidenav-right="true"></nav>
```

The `style` parameter can only be seen in the browser inspector and not in the code editor. When I write `style:350px`, it is removed and overwritten with `style: 240px`.

How can I change this width parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that is the [sidebar from Tailwind Elements](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/navigation/sidenav), not the Tailwind library itself.

As per [the documentation](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/navigation/sidenav/#api-section-options), you can customize the sidebar width by setting the `sidebarWidth` option. Since you seem to be using the attributes technique to add options, you would add `data-te-sidebarnav-width="350"` to change the width to `350px`:

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/css/tw-elements.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<nav id="cart-nav" class="fixed right-0 top-0 z-[1035] h-screen w-96 translate-x-full overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-[0_4px_12px_0_rgba(0,0,0,0.07),_0_2px_4px_rgba(0,0,0,0.05)] data-[te-sidenav-hidden='false']:-translate-x-0 sidenav-primary group/ps [overflow-anchor:none] [overflow-style:none] touch-none" data-te-sidenav-init="" data-te-sidenav-hidden="false" data-te-sidenav-right="true" data-te-sidenav-width="350"></nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/js/tw-elements.umd.min.js"></script>
```